# Add unspecified options to cli command using python-click

Tags: python, python-click

I would like to add unspecified options to the cli command using python-click library. So my cli function could look like the following

```
$ my-cmd --option1 value1 --options2 value2 --unknown_var value3
```

My current code:

```
import click

@click.option('--option1')
@click.option('--option2')
@click.command(name='my-cmd')
def cli(option1, option2):
  click.echo("my test")
```

I would like to see something like the following:

```
import click

@click.option('--option1')
@click.option('--option2')
@click.command(name='my-cmd')
def cli(option1, option2, **kwargs):
  click.echo("my test")
  # Manually manage **kwargs
```

Comment: If you are willing to accept `my-cmd --option1 value1 -- --unknown_var value3 --another-unknown-var value 4` then you can use [Option Like Arguments](http://click.pocoo.org/5/arguments/#option-like-arguments) and [Variadic Arguments](http://click.pocoo.org/5/arguments/#variadic-arguments)  together.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can pass `context` with `ignore_unknown_options` and `allow_extra_args` settings, the extra arguments will be collected in `context.args` list (`['--unknown_var', 'value3', '--unknown_var2', 'value4']`). Then you can transform it to dict.

```
import click

@click.command(name='my-cmd', context_settings=dict(
    ignore_unknown_options=True,
    allow_extra_args=True,
))
@click.option('--option1')
@click.option('--option2')
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx, option1, option2):
    click.echo({ctx.args[i][2:]: ctx.args[i+1] for i in range(0, len(ctx.args), 2)})
```

example

```
python cli.py --option1 value1 --option2 value2 --unknown_var value3 --unknown_var2 value4
>> {'unknown_var2': 'value4', 'unknown_var': 'value3'}
```

See [Forwarding Unknown Options](http://click.pocoo.org/5/advanced/#forwarding-unknown-options).

Comment: In addition, if you want to support args (starting with -) and options (starting with --) you might want to use something like `{(ctx.args[i][2:] if str(ctx.args[i]).startswith("--") else ctx.args[i][1:]): ctx.args[i+1] for i in range(0, len(ctx.args), 2)}`

Comment: I would use a stripping and splitting with a list comprehension. This looks way cleaner: `data = dict([item.strip('--').split('=') for item in ctx.args])`

Comment: Make sure you account for boolean flags 
`params = {k.lstrip('--'): ctx.args[i + 1] if not (i + 1 >= len(ctx.args) or ctx.args[i + 1].startswith('--')) else True for i, k in enumerate(ctx.args) if k.startswith('--')}` (ugly one line so it fits in a comment)