# Python click pass unspecified number of kwargs

Tags: python, dictionary, keyword-argument, python-click

Recently discovered click and I would like to pass an unspecified number of kwargs to a click command. Currently this is my command:

```
@click.command()
@click.argument('tgt')
@click.argument('fun')
@click.argument('args', nargs=-1)
def runner(tgt, fun, args):
    req = pyaml.p(meh.PostAdapter(tgt, fun, *args))
    click.echo(req)
```

However when using nargs anything more than 1 is passed as a tuple ([docs][1]) and I cannot `type=dict` that unfortunately.

But it should be possible to do something like this:

`command positional1 positional2 foo='bar' baz='qux' xxx='yyy'`

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions, in the meantime I will keep chipping away at this myself.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944131/add-unspecified-options-to-cli-command-using-python-click

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the link that @rmn provided, I rewrote my click command as follows:

```
@click.command(context_settings=dict(
    ignore_unknown_options=True,
    allow_extra_args=True,
))
@click.pass_context
def runner(ctx, tgt, fun):
    d = dict()
    for item in ctx.args:
        d.update([item.split('=')])
    req = pyaml.p(meh.PostAdapter(tgt, fun, d))
    click.echo(req)
```

Which allows me to issue the following command properly:

`mycmd tgt fun foo='bar' baz='qux' xxx='yyy'`

Comment: I would use a list comprehension here: `d = dict([item.strip('--').split('=') for item in ctx.args])`

Comment: Make sure you account for boolean flags 
`params = {k.lstrip('--'): ctx.args[i + 1] if not (i + 1 >= len(ctx.args) or ctx.args[i + 1].startswith('--')) else True for i, k in enumerate(ctx.args) if k.startswith('--')}` (ugly one line so it fits in a comment)