# Arbitrary command line keywords with Python's click library

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I have a command line tool built with Python's [click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/) library.  I want to extend this tool to use user-defined keywords like the following:

```
$ my-cli --foo 10 --bar 20
```

Normally I would add the following code to my command

```
@click.option('--foo', type=int, default=0, ...)
```

However in my case there are a few keywords that are user defined.  I won't know that the user wants to sepcify foo or bar or something else ahead of time.

#### One solution

Currently, my best solution is to use strings and do my own parsing

```
$ my-cli --resources "foo=10 bar=20"
```

Which would work, but is slightly less pleasant.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944131/add-unspecified-options-to-cli-command-using-python-click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
import click


@click.command(context_settings=dict(ignore_unknown_options=True,))
@click.option('-v', '--verbose', is_flag=True, help='Enables verbose mode')
@click.argument('extra_args', nargs=-1, type=click.UNPROCESSED)
def cli(verbose, extra_args):
    """A wrapper around Python's timeit."""
    print(verbose, extra_args)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

Test:

```
$ python test.py --foo 12
False ('--foo', '12')

$ python test.py --foo 12 -v
True ('--foo', '12')
```

From: http://click.pocoo.org/5/advanced/#forwarding-unknown-options