# Is there a more idiomatic way to take a list of args using Python's Click?

Tags: python, python-click

I can write the following:

```
import click


@click.command()
@click.option('--things', callback=lambda _,__,x: x.split(',') if x else [])
def fun(things):
    print('You gave me these things: {}'.format(things))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fun()
```

This appears to work, at least if I save it as `fun.py` I can run:

```
$ python fun.py
You gave me these things: []
$ python fun.py --things penguins,knights,"something different"
You gave me these things: ['penguin', 'knights', 'something different']
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to write this code using Click, or is that pretty much it?

Comment: (caveat, I'm not a click user so take anything I say with a huge grain of salt) -- According to the documentation,  ["only a fixed number of arguments is supported"](http://click.pocoo.org/5/options/#multi-value-options).  So I think this strategy is pretty optimal.  Obviously, if you're going to use this a lot then a suitably named helper is nicer than the `lambda`.  You can also do `multiple=True` to support `python fun.py --thing penguin --thing knights ...`, but that changes the commandline structure.

Comment: I've thought about taking that approach and somehow splitting/concatenating the lists. Not sure if that would work well for me, though.

Comment: http://click.pocoo.org/5/options/#multi-value-options ?

Comment: It looks to me like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40749912/1286571) is relevant here too. The trade off is that because it uses arguments, click won't automatically format `--things` in help.

Answer (score 4):

What I think you want is the 'multiple' option for parameters. E.g.

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--thing', multiple=True)
def fun(thing):
    print('You gave me these things: {}'.format(thing))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fun()
```

And then to pass multiple values, you specify `thing` multiple times. Like so:

```
$ python fun.py
You gave me these things: ()

$ python fun.py --thing me
You gave me these things: ('me',)

$ python fun.py --thing penguins --thing knights --thing "something different"
You gave me these things: ('penguins', 'knights', 'something different')
```